# Get system (context) menu

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

[image]I made custom window frame and window title bar etc. with Qt::FramelessWindowHint.
But I'm missing system menu(which you get when right-clicked app. icon or the app. name in task bar, and so on) now.
How can I get system menu and show it?
I am working on linux c++/Qt

Comment: you want a context menü for your app? is that your question?

Comment: Yes. But I want system default context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own **context menu** and make it like **system context menu**.

Just use `.qrc` file to add `.css` file with your style (like system context menu).

Example for style:

```
 QMenu::item
 {
     background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);
     color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 }

 QMenu::item:selected
 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 85, 127);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 }
```

And you can make it via setStyleSheet() method without `.qrc` file:

```
QString  menuStyle(
           "QMenu::item{"
           "background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);"
           "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
           "}"
           "QMenu::item:selected{"
           "background-color: rgb(0, 85, 127);"
           "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
           "}"
        );

  this->setStyleSheet(menuStyle);
```

How to create **context menu** example here: https://evileg.com/en/post/76/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like to have system default context menu also how I should implement action "Move workspace right in linux".

Comment: but what do you mean wth "system default CM" there is no such a thing... every app defines its own context menu depending on what they want to offer to the tool's user...

Comment: Please see image attached above. I want the same but for my custom title bar.

Comment: @ArmenGishyan The menu shown in your question is a property of the window manager being used and has nothing to do with Linux as such.  Likewise for actions such as "Move workspace right".